# Round only three corners of a rectangle in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, corners

I am trying to round only three corners of the following rectangle below. I know this is easy to do in Illustrator CC, but I don't have it.

In Illustrator CS6 you can only round the corners of a shape using **Effect > Stylize > Round Corners**. However, this results in all of the corners being rounded.

Is there any way to make only three corners of the rectangle rounded using Illustrator CS6? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I usually open InDesign > Rectangle Tool > Make a Rectangle > Object Menu > Corner Options > Uncheck the Chain in the middle > Change the shape of any of the corners as desired > Copy Shape > Paste in AI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After downloading this free **Rounded Corner Graphic Style Library** from [creativepro.com](https://creativepro.com/round-corners-quickly-illustrator/)

- Load the library in your Illustrator version
- Apply the desire round corner style
- Apply a 3D Rotate

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this nice script; **[Round Any Corner](https://gist.github.com/zalmanlew/fcbf311cf504a001577d8d424336e592#file-round-any-corner-jsx)** by *Hiroyuki Sato*, you can download their entire package of useful scripts from their [website](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/).

---

Using the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) select the corners you want to round.

Now run the script and choose a corner radius, you can also preview the change before applying it.

[image: GIF showing proccess]

<sup>▲ This script also works on non rectangular paths.</sup>

Comment: This link is dead please refresh your answer

Comment: @MicroMachine thanks for letting me know, updated.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and it looked like it was rounding all the corners of the entered value - did you check it ?

Comment: @MicroMachine yes, I used the script (in the inline GIF you can see it in action). I just tested it again with the latest Illustrator (CC 2022) and it still works fine. Make sure you are using the *Direct Selection Tool* (A) in order to select only specific corners.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround without downloading nor installing anything:

Make a rounded rectangle and shear & rotate it to the wanted position. As well you can use a straight rectangle, shear & rotate it and add the round corners effect. Expand the appearance to fix the effect and make all fully editable.

Then rectify one of the round corners. An example:

[image]

1. the shape with four corners rounded
2. Draw 2 straight lines along the sides; they should snap perfectly if you have smart guides and snap to point ON, no other snaps!
3. Make the lines to cross. Scale the lines up by dragging, hold Shift to retain the directions
4. Select all, join the areas with the Shape builder, delete the remnants of the lines.

DONE!

Comment: Although I like this because you can do it in Illustrator without downloading anything, it is a bit of an *unnecessarily* dragged out process. Scripts are the *easiest* thing to run in Illustrator, I can't believe I didn't know about or utilize scripts earlier on. (In my GIF you see that I don't even load the script into the script folder, I just *drag+drop* them into Ai for quick use.)