# Rounding corners warps object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-effects

As shown in the picture I just want to make those 3 ends more round like a half circle maybe, but when I try to do that with **Effect → Stylize → Round Corners** it deforms/warps the whole object?

Why does it do this and how can I fix this or is there maybe another way to make the corners round (I know you can click on the round corner button thingy but that doesn't make them round enough)
[image]

Comment: What version of Illustrator are you running?

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118887/63979) will be very helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the nodes with the Direct Selection Tool and use the [Live Corners Widget](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html):

[image]

If your Illustrator version doesn't have Live Corners Widget, make your shape with paths, group them and from the Appearance Panel add two different stroke sizes and color with round caps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the arcs are composed of only two nodes and when the rounding is performed, those nodes react in a manner inappropriate to your objective.

Have you considered to add a supporting node "inboard" of each of the corners? The extra points would maintain the existing arc structure and allow for the rounded corners.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution if they want to use Illustrators built-in corner rounding style. I outline it [here in this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/104353/63979).