# How do I edit type in Illustrator to round off corners?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, cs6

Recently I wanted to recreate Fasthosts's logo for a small project of mine.

I found out which font it is, but the styling is a bit different than in the logo. It looks like the top of the letters / font is rounded or curved to the right.

I've highlighted the parts in red boxes, to give you an idea what I'am talking about.
[image]

To be honest, I have a little experience in Illustrator, but have no idea how to style letters / fonts like this. I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: btw the font looks quite different; the logo seems to use a bolder version of the font. Also not recommended to do this in a non-vector software.

Comment: I think you can do it using the script mentioned in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118887/63979).

Answer (score 2):

You have to break the text into outlines (menu **Type > Convert to Outlines** / Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> / Win: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) then you can edit the points individually. You can't edit points directly on text before that.

I recommend you find some basic Illustrator tutorials because it doesn't get easier from there on!

Comment: Also, some Illustrator versions don't work on that command. So for that, go to Type > Convert to outlines. Once done, press A for direct selection tool then the circles that come up on each corner of the type, drag them to round them up. Neat.

Comment: @Abhimanyu that's the default shortcut AFAIK, but I added the menu item as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, these don't look like the same font, and they are not the same weight.  Sometimes companies will have a custom font designed specifically for them, which may not be available to the general public for download. Sometimes a designer can also modify existing letter forms for a one-off custom design.

To edit the letter forms you would need to turn the text to outlines.

**In Illustrator** you can do that using *Object > Expand* or *Type > Create Outlines*.

You can move anchors by selecting them with the Direct Selection Tool (A).

In Illustrator CC* you can round corners by selecting and moving the rounded corner widget.

*Example*

[image]

**In Inkscape** you can turn text to outlines using *Path > Object to Path*

You can move the nodes by selecting them with the Edit Paths by Nodes tool (F2). You can add nodes by double clicking on the path, and change nodes to smooth nodes in the Tool Controls Bar along the top, and adjust the Bézier handles

*Example*

[image]

***Note:** If you don't have Illustrator CC with the round corner widget functionality, you can use the same technique described for Inkscape. Add anchors using the Add Anchor Point tool, convert to smooth in the tool options along the top, and adjust the Bézier handles.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit roundoff coners by first converting the letters into an outline
you can do that by going to the "Type" menu bar and click create outline then you can use the direct selection tool to edit the coners of the letters [image]